# can you use IF statement in inline Azure Powershell script in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I have a task in Azure Devops which builds a VM

Task 1 builds a VM
Task 2 adds datadisks if required

so in task 2 I have an inline powershell script but when i run it it gives an error
" The term 'n' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. Not sure why it is giving the error?
"

```
 ###Azure Devops pipeline variable is $(datadisk1required) this has the value 'n'
$datadisk1required = $(datadisk1required)
if ($datadisk1required -eq "n")
{
write-host "datadisk1 not required"
write-host $datadisk1required
}
```

Comment: Put quotation marks around `$(datadisk1required)`, otherwise the resulting line will be `$datadisk1required = n`, which is why PowerShell interprets `n` as a command name

Comment: that worked as expected

Answer (score 2):

The substitution of AzDO variables in the script happens before PowerShell runs, and that means that if the inline script definition is:

```
$powerShellVariable = $(azVariable)
```

and the value of the `azVariable` variable in the task is "string", the resulting script passed to PowerShell will be:

```
$powerShellVariable = string
```

PowerShell will interpret the bare word `string` as a command name, hence the error.

Put quotation marks in place around the AzDO variable macro and it'll work:

```
$datadisk1required = '$(datadisk1required)'
```